# Mouse Pointer Animation on Slider

Tags: jquery, mouse-cursor

I have viewed this mouse pointer effect on few websites and wondering if you know how is it created or any tutorials available:

http://2f-design.fr/themes/starry/

Comment: they have used html5 canvas element for that effect. 1. Create a canvas element. 2. Position it correctly. 3. Based on mouse position draw something on canvas (redraw every time mouse moves)

Answer (score 0):

It's using HTML5 canvas (raw).

However, there are many libraries that make working with canvas easier. The better ones use webgl when available (for better performance) and fallback to canvas if webgl isn't supported.

Take a look a [pixi.js](http://www.pixijs.com/) and their [examples](http://www.pixijs.com/examples/). It's a solid rendering engine with good [documentation](http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/docs/).

Of course, there are plenty of "raw" [canvas tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial).